# Get the label value for a leafNode in a toolBar

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have created a toolBar with a number of basicLeafNodes. In some JS in the style property I would like to get the label value for the basicLeafNode. I tried this.label but that throws and error. If I could get the label value then I could write a very generalized block of code that would be the same for every leaf in the toolBar. Which would be easier to maintain and extend.
This is a long way from a show stopper but it would be neat,

Comment: Where is that code going to be? Maybe you need to get parent of "this" before calling "label".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, because `this` represents the toolbar object, not the leaf node (it's all one giant object).

However, you might use `repeatTreeNode` and some Javascript magic (or preferably a managed bean), all values can be calculated and management could be easier for the future.

```
    <xe:toolbar id="toolbar1">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:repeatTreeNode var="item">
                <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript: 
  [{
    "label": "Open",
    "href": "http://www.openntf.org"
  },
  {
    "label": "Search",
    "href": "http://www.google.com"
  }]
}]]></xe:this.value>
                <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode href="#{item.href}" label="#{item.label}">
                        <xe:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:"color:"+(item.label=="Open"?"blue":"red")}]]></xe:this.style>
                    </xe:basicLeafNode>
                </xe:this.children>
            </xe:repeatTreeNode>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>
    </xe:toolbar>
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: And probably even more ideal would be to compute the `styleClass` instead of the `style` so if you change your mind later about what specific visual attributes you want applied, you can simply update a style sheet instead of making further changes to your XPage code. :)

Comment: Thanks Serdar will look into doing something like that. I'm already computing the styleClass checking if it is the selected Node.